# Patterns for Implementing Resource Expansion in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to implement RESTful services that support Resource Expansion, so that services are self contained but if clients want to limit the number of service calls that they make, they can do so via a query string parameter. Some examples of Resource Expansion are:

- [Stormpath API](https://stormpath.com/blog/linking-and-resource-expansion-rest-api-tips/)
- [Netflix API](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/REST_API_Conventions#0_pgfId-1007760)

Let's say I have 2 services, each in their own CSPROJ:

1. ACME.AuthorsService
2. ACME.BooksService

The ACME.AuthorsService's controller has a method to get an author by ID:

```
// GET /api/author/1
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
{
    Author author = await _authorRepo.GetById(id);
    if (author == null)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, author);
}
```

Which will return information about an author:

```
{
    "Name": "Alan Moore",
    "Href": "https://acme.org/api/author/1",
    "Books": [
        {
            "Id": 9999,
            "Title": "V for Vendetta",
            "Href": "https://acme.org/api/book/9999"
        },
        {
            "Id": 8888,
            "Title": "Neonomicon",
            "Href": "https://acme.org/api/book/8888"            
        }
    ]
}
```

Similarly, the ACME.BooksService's controller has a method to get a book by ID:

```
// GET /api/book/1
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
{
    Book book = await _bookRepo.GetById(id);
    if (book == null)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, book);
}
```

Which will return detailed information about a book:

```
{
    "Id": 9999,
    "Title": "V for Vendetta",
    "ISBN-10": "140120841X"
    "ISBN-13": "978-1401208417",
    "Pages": 296,
    "Href": "https://acme.org/api/book/9999"
}
```

With Resource Expansion, a client should be able to request that given field with an "Href" property should have its result expanded. For example, requesting https://acme.org/api/author/1?expand=books should yield:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Alan Moore",
    "Href": "https://acme.org/api/author/1",
    "Books": [
        {
            "Id": 9999,
            "Title": "V for Vendetta",
            "ISBN-10": "140120841X"
            "ISBN-13": "978-1401208417",
            "Pages": 296,
            "Href": "https://acme.org/api/book/9999"
        },
        {
            "Id": 8888,
            "Title": "Neonomicon",
            "ISBN-10": "1592911315",
            "ISBN-13": "978-1592911318",
            "Pages": 176,
            "Href": "https://acme.org/api/book/8888"            
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to think of some strategies/patterns for implementing Resource Expansion, in ASP.NET Web API, in such away that any of the services (ACME.AuthorsService, ACME.BooksService, etc.) can expand an item based on its name and the availability of an "Href" property.

So in the above example, when the expand query string property is detected, the name of the Property to expand is retrieved (Ex: books) and Author model is returned with a Books collection property, is it best to:

- follow the associated Href property in the AuthorService controller's Get() method with something like HttpClient to make the request to the Book service and mash the responses together
- Somehow get a reference to the BookService's controller or repo to get the book info?
- OData's $expand (I only learned about this just recently after [Googling around](https://www.google.com/#q=resource+expansion+asp.net+web+api))?
- something else?

Of course, the solution shouldn't be coupled to Authors and Books. It should be common to handle any sort of Resource Expansion scenario where an "Href" property is available.

Comment: This is a perfect case for OData and the $select or $expand properties. You could employ these in Web API 2 to accomplish precisely what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, David. Will OData play nicely with Web API's content negotiation, or is it restricted to certain types?

Comment: Plays nicely with the negotiation; that's why it's natively supported. It sometimes creates an anonymous type, but most serializers can handle that without concern (XML, JSON, etc.)

Comment: Please let us know you proceed, I'm investigating this very same question.

Comment: Interested if you found a solution that didn't use OData as it seems to be tightly coupled with Entity Framework from what I've seen.